# Currency format issue

Tags: android

```
 fun convertText(value: Long, country: String?): String {

            val currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault())
            currencyFormatter.currency= Currency.getInstance(Locale("EN", country))
            currencyFormatter.isGroupingUsed = true
              return currencyFormatter.format(value)
        }
```

I am getting different currency name from server like CN, US etc and i need to show value with currency symbol. now i am getting response like :

**US$104,

  CN¥‎141**

How can i achieve answer like

**$104

¥‎141**